# Is it possible to render a PDF in sepia tones?

Tags: pdftex, pdf

Is it possible to render a PDF in sepia tones, both the font color and overall document background? Preferably using `pdflatex`.

The final effect could be something like this screenshot of Pocket in sepia mode.

[image: Screenshot of Pocket app with sepia theme]

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Font color, backgrounds, figures or something different? Do you have an example picture of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @benregn To do this well, you need to colour the font. Maybe you can use the chikenize package.

Comment: @TomBombadil: I added a screenshot. KeksDose: I cannot seem to find that package.

Comment: From the "Fishing with dynamite" series: we could submit the final `.pdf` file to ImageMagick's `convert` and apply the `-sepia-tone` effect, say `$ convert -sepia-tone 80% -density 400 mydoc.pdf -resize 25% newdoc.pdf`. The drawback of this approach is that ImageMagick will convert every single page of the document to an image, apply the sepia effect and then add it to the final `.pdf` file (not to mention the huge file size). Some screenshots from Marco's `mdframed` manual: [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4quYv.png) and [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FuB8n.png). `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: Hehe, nice one!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With the standard `xcolor` package, you can set the background color of your document using `\pagecolor`, and the text color using `\color`.

Here's a sample using the colors from your screenshot:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{myBGcolor}{HTML}{F6F0D6}
\definecolor{myTextcolor}{HTML}{4F452C}
\pagecolor{myBGcolor}
\color{myTextcolor}

\begin{document} 
When people face an uncertain situation\ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sepia color exists; `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} \color{Sepia}` and for the background I like `\definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}   
\pagecolor{fondpaille!90!black}   `