# is it possible to display color only in PDF viewer, not printed page?

Tags: color, printing

The `ocgcolorlinks` option to `hyperref` will let you have colorful links on the screen that are black (or more generally, the textcolor) when printed.

> [Is there a way to have coloured hyperref hyperlinks in the PDF, but have them print "as if" they were black?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4425/is-there-a-way-to-have-coloured-hyperref-hyperlinks-in-the-pdf-but-have-them-pr) **(yes there is!)**

I'm wondering if there is a way to do similar tricks with other applications of color in LaTeX?  For instance, I have in mind `\pagecolor` and `\color`.

## tl;dr:

> [Is it possible to render a PDF in sepia tones?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60371/is-it-possible-to-render-a-pdf-in-sepia-tones) ... but have it print in black and white?

Comment: Note that the question [How can I have text colored on screen and black on printing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22609/how-can-i-have-text-colored-on-screen-and-black-on-printing) does not address the question considered here but only considers colored links.

Comment: This answer on [Implementing full-page Screen-Only & Print-Only in PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167846/implementing-full-page-screen-only-print-only-in-pdf/175069#175069) gives a proof of concept, but requires that the text be entered twice, which isn't suitable for day-to-day use.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276554/2388 for pagecolor

Comment: Use a b&w only printer?  The Color/Desaturate option from Gimp (for example) will convert color to shades of gray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a useable work-around for the exact use case I had in mind, following answer from [automatically inject code into preamble in cascading manner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283806/automatically-inject-code-into-preamble-in-cascading-manner).

## spdflatex

Make this executable.

```
#!/bin/bash

pdflatex -jobname=$1 \\RequirePackage{sepia} \\input{$1}
```

## sepia.sty

Save this in `~/texmf/tex/latex/mystyles/`

```
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}    
\pagecolor{fondpaille!90!black}
\AtBeginDocument{\color{Sepia}}
```

## Compile files with `spdflatex` for sepia tones, `pdflatex` for b/w.