# automatically inject code into preamble in cascading manner

Tags: compiling

Is there a standard way to automatically inject certain files into a LaTeX preamble?  Naturally I could write some patch code for this but I thought I should check if there's some "preferred" way to accomplish the job.

Inspired by [Creating a default preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278817/creating-a-default-preamble) the hypothetical MWE is as follows:

## mypreamble.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mypreamble}
 [2015/11/18 MyPreamble]
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\endinput
```

## file.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\wow}[1]{\textbf{Wow, much #1!}}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{This works, trust me.}
\wow{color}
\end{document}
```

Invocation would then be something like:

```
smart-pdflatex --with-style mypreamble.sty file.tex
```

Output to be the same as running

```
pdflatex smart-file.tex
```

## smart-file.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mypreamble}
\newcommand{\wow}[1]{\textbf{Wow, much #1!}}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{This works, trust me.}
\wow{color}
\end{document}
```

---

Note, the above examples use the `article` class, but I'm hoping for a solution that also works with `memoir`, etc.; and similarly, it would be great to have a recipe that works for `xelatex` as well as `pdflatex`.

At the moment the above examples are working only for the `article`×`pdflatex` "quadrant", using the recipe from David Carlisle's answer below.  Switching `article` to `memoir`, I get

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \@namelet already defined.
```

And with `xelatex` I get

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

---

## Update @cfr, Dec 19 2015, 0123 UTC:

For example, with `mypreamble.sty` as above, and adjusting the compilation command following suggestions from comments below, I try to compile

## file.tex

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newcommand{\wow}[1]{\textbf{Wow, much #1!}}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{This works, trust me.}
\wow{color}
\end{document}
```

with the command (all on one line, no extra spaces):

```
pdflatex -jobname=file \\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}\\usepackage{mypreamble}\\renewcommand\\documen‌​tclass[2][]{}\\input{file}
```

and I get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: \documen undefined.
```

## Update - invisible character (oops)

The command above looks the same as this one but contains an invisible character, which is the source of the error.  The following command works with `memoir`.

```
pdflatex -jobname=file \\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}\\usepackage{mypreamble}\\renewcommand\\documentclass[2][]{}\\input{file}
```

Comment: `mypreamble.sty` is just for loading some package? or it is a complete preamble?

Comment: In my use case it should just load a package.  I'll adjust the example to clarify.

Comment: You have an invisible character between the `n` and the `t` in the final `\documentclass` in the command line. If you eliminate that, it works fine. (Well, I commented the preamble package as well, obviously from `file.tex`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pdflatex -jobname=file \\RequirePackage{mypreamble} \\input{file}
```

would work in the basic case (you may or may not need to double the `\\` depending on your commandline shell)

If requirements vary (e.g. for `xelatex`+`memoir`), some adjustments are needed.

```
xelatex -jobname=file \\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}\\usepackage{mypreamble}\\renewcommand\\documentclass[2][]{}\\input{file}
```

Comment: `pdflatex -jobname=file ...` to be complete

Comment: this can't work with some packages that redefine class commands. One should try `pdflatex -jobname=file \documentclass{article}\usepackage{mypreamble}\renewcommand{\documentclass}[1]{}\input{file}` or `pdflatex -jobname=file \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}\usepackage{mypreamble}\renewcommand{\documentclass}[2][]{}\input{file}`

Comment: OK, for example it doesn't appear to work with `memoir`.  But your suggestions aren't immediately fixing it.

Comment: @JoeCorneli What exactly did you try? You'd want something like `pdflatex -jobname=file \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}\usepackage{mypreamble}\renewcommand\documentclass[2][]{}\input{file}` where `file.tex` is the name of your `.tex` file and `mypreamble.sty` is the preamble. In some cases, of course, you'll doubtless still have trouble, but I suppose it would work in simple cases. Though I would not recommend doing it.

Comment: @cfr, exactly that command (plus extra backslashes) does not work for me.  I get `! LaTeX Error: \documen undefined.`

Comment: Please update your question with a complete example and the specific command you are using, including any extra anythings.  I don't even know how to try to reproduce that error. It looks as if you added a space into the command name or something else LaTeX wouldn't complain about `\documen` because it would not be fed any such command.

Comment: That's a continuous command with no line breaks. There is a space between `pdflatex` and `-jobname...` and another between the name of the file and `\documentclass...` but there is no space anywhere else, certainly not between `\documen` and `tclass...`.

Comment: @JoeCorneli ^^^

Comment: Please see the update @cfr above.

Comment: @JoeCorneli It is just an invisible character in your command line. It works if you remove it.

Comment: Amazing! I wonder where it came from.  Anyway, I can confirm that it works, as you've suggested.